# PyOpenCL can't build the program in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyopencl

I'm trying to use PyOpenCL via SSH on Ubuntu, but when I get in the "prg = cl.Program(ctx, kernel).build()" it returns

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 141, in build
    options = options + ["-I", _find_pyopencl_include_path()]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 722, in _find_pyopencl_include_path
    from pkg_resources import Requirement, resource_filename
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`
```

The program I'm trying to build is the oficial from PyOpenCL documentation (https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/index.html).

Comment: Do you have the package python-pkg-resources installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to install the python-pkg-resources package, which provides the python package called "pkg_resources".

For other distributions, the setuptools for python package might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem that u have mentioned above n the solution worked for me is that i have to update my setuptools
`pip install --upgrade setuptools`
n after doing that it works...
its also handy for some other packages.